# Linear Transformation with Array Elements

Tags: python, linear-regression, linear-algebra, montecarlo, markov-chains

I am attempting to solve for a transformation matrix where each element of my two known matrices are arrays. I have two matrices:

```py
    a= np.array([
        [data['10']['ann1'], data['25']['ann1'], data['50']['ann1'], data['100']['ann1']],
        [data['10']['ann2'], data['25']['ann2'], data['50']['ann2'], data['100']['ann2']],
        [data['10']['ann3'], data['25']['ann3'], data['50']['ann3'], data['100']['ann3']],
        [data['10']['ann4'], data['25']['ann4'], data['50']['ann4'], data['100']['ann4']],
        [data['10']['ann5'], data['25']['ann5'], data['50']['ann5'], data['100']['ann5']]])
    b= np.array([
        [data['target']['ann1']],
        [data['target']['ann2']],
        [data['target']['ann3']],
        [data['target']['ann4']],
        [data['target']['ann5']]])
```

where I need to find a solution matix x where for ax=b. Each element (e.g. `data['10']['ann1']`) is a 1-D matrix of length 32, but the elements of the solution matrix should be single values. Is there a way in python to do a linear regression or MCMC fit on this type of system?

Comment: Does "ax" mean "np.dot(a,x)" in "ax=b"? Could you provide a numerical example of smaller size (say, with 3 instead of 32 for the inner matrices) demonstrating what is the expected result?